# Looking for the name of a phenomenon

Tags: cognitive-psychology

My old psych teacher talked to us about how after the first person ran a 4 minute mile, the subsequent year or so many others managed it too. And he said that when people know something to be possible, they're more likely to achieve it.
Im not even sure, if there's research to back it up but I was wondering a) if there's a name for it, I assumed "power of belief" maybe? b) If there's any scientific validity to it.